# How to set Async-Supported flag for the Filters which are getting called via Spring DelegatingFilterProxy chain?

Tags: asynchronous, spring-security, java-8, tomcat8, servlet-3.0

I am developing a servlet which will support Async operation.
This servlet will be called via multiple filters. Some of the filters are as part of FilterProxyChain which is created via DelegatingFilterProxy.

If we have to start an Async Context from a servlet, then the Filter Chain should also support Async operation. Else below exception gets thrown -

> 28-Jul-2017 09:41:51.196 SEVERE [http-nio-127.0.0.1-7441-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [eventBus] in context with path [] threw exception
>    java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1630)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.startAsync(Request.java:1623)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.startAsync(RequestFacade.java:1030)
>           at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:379)
>           at javax.servlet.ServletRequestWrapper.startAsync(ServletRequestWrapper.java:379)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.HttpServlet3RequestFactory$Servlet3SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.startAsync(HttpServlet3RequestFactory.java:167)
>           at com.amdocs.vshield.vsm.asyncrest.VsmAsyncRestController.doGet(VsmAsyncRestController.java:89)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)

Some of the filters which are called via DelegatingFilterProxy are not configured in web.xml explicitly.
So how to make these filters to support Async ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what they say here: https://spring.io/blog/2012/12/17/spring-security-3-2-m1-highlights-servlet-3-api-support/#servlet3-async

So:

1. Spring Security version must be at least 3.2
2. `web.xml`'s `webapp` element must have `version="3.0"`
3. Your `DelegatingFilterProxy` `<filter>` element must have `<async-supported>true</async-supported>`
4. Its mapping should have the following:

`<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>ASYNC</dispatcher>`

Comment: Its not working. Still it fails with the same exception. How we can configure the filter to support Async requests which are called via DelegatingProxyFilter ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the root cause. There were some errors in web.xml due to which it servlets/filters not properly deployed. Dont know why tomcat didnt failed to start in that case.
You have to add  for all the filters(Coming in filter chain)/ servlets. And with value as True.